# rake task to populate new column in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, rake

I added a new column to one of my tables with

```
class AddLocationToHome < ActiveRecord::Mirgation
    def change
        add_column :home, :location, :string
    end
end
```

The home table already has data that was populate from a rake task that reads from a csv file.
I added the header and new data to my csv file, but how do I run my rake to import just that new column of data?

My rake import is something like this

```
require 'csv'

namespace :db do
    desc "Import the location of existing homes"
    task :import_locations => environment do
         csv_text = File.read('db/imports/homes.csv')
         csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
         csv.each do (row)
             !# not sure how to import just the new rows from the csv?
         end
     end
 end
```

thanks!

Comment: You need to somehow detect whether the row just read from the csv file exists in the database. For example, if you're reading user records you could check whether the newly read record's email exists in the database -- and only create a new record if not. You may have to check multiple fields if you don't have something as convenient as email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a reasonable start there. Within that commented space, though, here's what you'll need to do:

- Based on the data in the other CSV columns, find the correct Home instance in your DB. (Something like `Home.where(col1: row['col1'])` but using enough columns to get a proper match.)
- Update that instance with the new column. (`home.update_attribute(location: row['location']`)

...and on to the next. It's going to pummel your DB with queries for a while, but the only way around that is to load the entire table into memory.